# Calling a function on a pointer from a std::list<Shape*>::iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

I have a basic polymorphism example in C++ with the following structure.

```
struct Shape {
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

struct Circle : public Shape {
    virtual void draw() {
        cout << "drawing circle" << endl;
    }
};

struct Triangle : public Shape {
    virtual void draw() {
        cout << "drawing triangle" << endl;
    }
};
```

I have a function using this setup to call the draw function as such:

```
void drawShapes(list<Shape*> shapes) {
    list<Shape*>::iterator pShape = shapes.begin();
    list<Shape*>::iterator pEnd = shapes.end();

    for (; pShape != pEnd; pShape++) {
        pShape->draw();
    }
}
```

This is exactly how the example is setup in the book I am reading. I am getting the following error when I try to compile this.

```
expression must have a pointer-to-class type
```

I fixed this by changing `pShape->draw();` to `(*pShape)->draw()`.

I then submitted this as a possible error to the writer of the book, to which he responded

"That's not the case, actually, because std::list::iterator has an operator->() function which resolves the iterator to a T* (in this case, Shape*)."

I still can't get the original version to compile though. I am using the compiler bundled with VS2015 to do these test. Does anyone know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Terrible response. May I ask what is the book?

Comment: Sure, everyone makes mistakes. But he should try it at least before responding.

Comment: Since pShape is an iterator, deref'ing the iterator produces the original T value, in this case: Shape*, which then must be deref'd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, and the author is wrong. `std::list<T>::iterator::operator*` returns a `T*`, this is true. But in this case, `T` is `Shape*`, which makes `T* == Shape**`. You need to dereference it once to get a `Shape*`. That is why `pShape->draw()` fails, but `(*pShape)->draw()` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
pShape->draw();
```

should indeed be

```
(*pShape)->draw();
```